# MoveIt fails to control arm, no arm_controller action client

Tags: moveit, arm-controller, ros-industrial, universal-robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using the hydro-devel branch of the universal_robot package to attempt to control a UR-5. I start move_group and moveit_rviz and rviz loads properly and displays the correct current state of the arm. I am also able to plan movements for the arm properly, however, every time I try to execute those planned movements, this shows up in moveit's terminal window:
EDIT: (text would not show up properly, here is a pastebin link: pastebin.com/e0VGVdFU )

it appears as though I do not have arm_controller either installed or initialized properly, and I have not been able to find any information relating to the installation or setup of this package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172938/moveit-fails-to-control-arm,-no-arm_controller-action-client/) by [airplanesrule](https://answers.ros.org/users/18786/airplanesrule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has come up before, and I think the UR instructions / documentation could do with some work. In any case, this recent discussion on the mailinglist should provide you with enough information to get things working: [Universal Robots UR5 & UR10 packages](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/swri-ros-pkg-dev/5KBACyQNJro/2sf3GjrX44QJ).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0